# Trazer a segunda e terceira linha de uma consulta

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle-SQL

Tenho uma tabela que grava os registros de ponto que cada funcionário faz.
A tabela traz as seguintes informações:

```
(TABELA QUE ESTOU FAZENDO A CONSULTA)
Contrato | Data         | Hora
1        | 10/05/2018   | 07:00
1        | 10/05/2018   | 11:30
...
```

Preciso agora transpor essas colunas, trazendo essas batidas como colunas
(TABELA COMO EU QUERO):

```
Contrato   |   Data     | Hora 1 | Hora 2 | Hora 3 | Hora 4
```

Só que estou com dificuldade para trazer os registros, vejam ate onde eu fui:
(QUERY ATUAL)

```
select distinct ponto.contrato CONTRATO,
       ponto.datamarcacao DATA,
       (select min(ponto1.horamarcacao) 
               from metaminu.rhmarcpontoreg ponto1 
                      where ponto.contrato = ponto1.contrato
                      and ponto.datamarcacao = ponto1.datamarcacao) HORA1,
        (select max(ponto2.horamarcacao) 
               from metaminu.rhmarcpontoreg ponto2 
                      where ponto.contrato = ponto2.contrato
                      and ponto.datamarcacao = ponto2.datamarcacao) HORA2,
        (select max(ponto3.horamarcacao) 
               from metaminu.rhmarcpontoreg ponto3 
                     where ponto.contrato = ponto3.contrato
                     and ponto.datamarcacao = ponto3.datamarcacao) HORA3,
        (select max(ponto4.horamarcacao) 
               from metaminu.rhmarcpontoreg ponto4 
                    where ponto.contrato = ponto4.contrato
                    and ponto.datamarcacao = ponto4.datamarcacao) HORA4
                                from metaminu.rhmarcpontoreg ponto
                                     where ponto.contrato = 7878
                                     order by ponto.datamarcacao
```

Claro, mantive os "max" só como exemplo, pois os únicos campos corretos são o primeiro e último (que utilizei o min e o max). Como faria para popular os dados da 2 e 3 colunas? Alguma dica?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende muito de como é o funcionamento do seu sistema... e se a pessoa bater o ponto mais de 4x no dia... teria ver como fica isso aí...

Seguindo o código que você já colocou de exemplo, poderia ficar assim:

```
select
t.contrato,
t.data,
(select min(e1.hora) from tabela e1 where e1.contrato = t.contrato and e1.data = t.data) entrada1,
(select min(s1.hora) from tabela s1 where s1.contrato = t.contrato and s1.data = t.data and s1.hora > (select min(e1.hora) from tabela e1 where e1.contrato = t.contrato and e1.data = t.data)) saida1,
(select max(s2.hora) from tabela s2 where s2.contrato = t.contrato and s2.data = t.data and s2.hora < (select max(e2.hora) from tabela e2 where e2.contrato = t.contrato and e2.data = t.data)) entrada2,
(select max(e2.hora) from tabela e2 where e2.contrato = t.contrato and e2.data = t.data) saida2
from tabela t
```

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10f6b/8)

> Resultado:

```
CONTRATO    DATA                    ENTRADA1    SAIDA1  ENTRADA2    SAIDA2
1           2018-01-01 00:00:00.0   7           12      13          17
1           2018-01-01 00:00:00.0   7           12      13          17
1           2018-01-01 00:00:00.0   7           12      13          17
1           2018-01-01 00:00:00.0   7           12      13          17
2           2018-01-01 00:00:00.0   8           12      14          18
2           2018-01-01 00:00:00.0   8           12      14          18
2           2018-01-01 00:00:00.0   8           12      14          18
2           2018-01-01 00:00:00.0   8           12      14          18
1           2018-01-02 00:00:00.0   7           11      14          18
1           2018-01-02 00:00:00.0   7           11      14          18
1           2018-01-02 00:00:00.0   7           11      14          18
1           2018-01-02 00:00:00.0   7           11      14          18
```

> ps. Usei um campo `numeric` como hora, apenas de exemplo

Comment: Resolvido Rovann, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que voce tenha algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_foobar
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id ) VALUES ( 2 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id ) VALUES ( 3 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id ) VALUES ( 4 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id ) VALUES ( 5 );
```

Você pode ordernar o conteúdo da tabela de forma decrescente e recuperar apenas os dois primeiros registros:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tb_foobar
WHERE
  ROWNUM <= 2 
ORDER BY
  id DESC
```

Saída:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  5 |
|  4 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c92f75/3

Comment: Resolvido Lacobus, obrigado.